# call method from a component to main component angular2

Tags: html, function, angular, navbar

my issue here is that i have a component that has functions that i want my app.component.html to have access to

**book.component.html**

```
<div class="form-inline">
        <input id="inputSearchBar" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="Text">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" (click)="onSearch()">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Now this is currently working because i have this line of code on my book.component.html, what i want is to use this on my app.component.html inside the navbar

**app.component.html**

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" 
    data-toggle="collapse" 
    aria-controls="navbarColor01"
    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01" >
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['']">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['about']">About</a>
        </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['books']">Books</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Register</a>
        </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#" [routerLink]="['login']">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I want to have that searchbox as part of my navbar and it being functional, what should i add on my components or what should i do to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parent and child relation ship here. create component for search bar and add in the Parent component.

1)
create search component like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'search-component',
})
export class searchcomponent  { }
```

2) Add in the parent HTML

app.component.html

```
<header>
<search-component>  </search-component>
</header>
```

More info check this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: ty for the reply, but the thing is i have a lot more things in my book.component.html than that specific searchbox, if i were to use this then they all would appear on the navbar, i just want that specific line of code to show up there

Answer (score 0):

You can use service for this task:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: I'd have to check that out later cause it is a lot of info, thx for sharing, but i just thought there was a much simpler way to do that, i'll definitely check it out later tho.